# Webservice security concern

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I wrote a few web-services for my project and i call them using jQuery post in my website. As we all know that javascript is client side script which can be seen using inspect element or other means, and our code becomes visible to everyone who know a little bit about html.

So my question is how we can maintain security for our web-service, because in javascript anyone can see which web-service we called and what are the argument needed to execute that web-service. so how can we save our web-services from unauthorized use?

let say

`$.ajax({
    url : "http://www.example.com/myWebserviceURL.php",
    method : "post",
    data  : {
        var1 : "value1",
        var2 : "value2",
        varnN : "valueN",
    }, success : function(){
        //some actions to be done
    }
});`

Now if someone inspect my code, or uses firebug/ similar tool they can use my webservice without my permission.

Comment: You need to use Server Side Access Token (store in session) in Web API. So authorized users only have Access Token (stored in session).

Comment: Do you understand what i am saying?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi What is this Access Token?

Comment: Generate a unique id.and set it as AccessToken at time of login/authorization per user or session.same like API Key but Access Token has scope till session timeout or logout.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put **Authorization** with **Access Token**. Access Token only has **Authorized User**.
2. This Access Token can not accessible/passed in API. It is s**erver side authentication**.
3. No one can see it via Ajax Call with **inspect**.
4. User AccessToken Setted in **session** at **first time** **login/authorize** then it will be accessible throughout website. Out side ajax call will not have token in session and can not make **POST Call.**
   Although make ajax call to API fails as it is not authorized at sever side. :)